# Приведение bool к 1 или 0 с помощью указателей

Tags: c#, unsafe

Как из `true` получается 1 при использовании указателей? И почему именно 1 а не другое число как в случае с переменной `d`?

```
unsafe
{
   bool a = true;
   bool* b = &a;

   int c = (int*)b; //указатель на число 1, почему?
   int d = (int)b; //какое-то другое число, почему?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` - это адрес в памяти. При чем `bool*` это указатель на память, участок памяти размером 1 байт. А `int*` - указатель на участок памяти в 4 байта. То есть при обращении к участку памяти:

```
bool a = true;
bool* b = &a;
int number = *(int*)b;
```

...вы получите не только байт, содержащий `bool` единичку, но и соседние 3 байта, которые могут содержать вообще что угодно. То есть как повезет, либо там будут нули и вы получите 1, либо там будет что-то другое и вы получите другое число.

При обращении к самому указателю

```
int address = b;
```

Вы получите число, являющееся адресом в памяти. При этом приведение типа указателя не имеет значения. А имеет значение разрядность приложения. В x86 приложениях адрес в памяти 32 бита (4 байта), то есть `uint`, в x64 приложениях в 2 раза больше, то есть 8 байт или `ulong`. Поэтому для написания универсального кода при работе с адресами в неуправляемой области памяти, придуман класс `IntPtr` (`nint`). Он всегда имеет тот размер, который нужен для текущей разрядности приложения.

Если надо преобразовать `bool` в `int`, используя указатели, то делать это надо через указатель типа `byte`.

```cs
bool a = true;
bool* b = &a;
int number = *(byte*)b;
```

Вот так отработает безопасно не цепляя при чтении лишние байты памяти.

В обратном направлении тоже.

```cs
int* ptr = &number;
bool c = *(bool*)ptr;
```

Но и здесь есть нюанс. Этот код сработает не на всех процессорах. Есть формат чисел Big-Endian и Little-Endian. То есть оканчивающиеся старшим байтом и младшим байтом. Выше показанный код сработает только для Big-Endian, где младший байт вначале участка памяти. Чтобы сработало для Little-Endian, надо немного изменить последнюю строчку.

```cs
bool c = *((bool*)ptr + 3);
```

Но лучше для таких простых операций вообще не использовать `unsafe`, например.

```cs
int number = a ? 1 : 0;
```

Сейчас практически любые трюки можно вытворять с памятью не прибегая к небезопасному коду. Поэтому внутреннюю логику приложения на нем почти никогда не приходится строить.

---

Кстати, принято считать, что для `bool` значение `false` это `0`, а значение `true` это `1`. На самом деле это только наполовину правда. На уровне процессооа ветвление кода происходит только с помощью проверки на `0`. Например кусок ассемблерного кода.

```
mov eax, 1
cmp eax, 0
jz [какой-то адрес]
```

Где `jz` проверяет ZF флаг процессора, который устанавливается при вызове инструкции `cmp` проверяющей регистр `eax` на `0`. И если там `0`, переход происходит, если нет, то не происходит. Есть еще инструкция `jnz`, которая инвертирует условие перехода, типа шарпового `if (!a)`.

Другими словами если `bool` имеет значение `false`, то это точно `0`,  а если `true`, то это любое другое число, но не ноль. Например число `34` - это тоже `true`.

При работе с небезопасным кодом всю кучу этих нюансов следует учитывать. На самом деле, почти всё зависит от того, каких инструкций нагенерит JIT, поэтому я просто советую запомнить, что `0` - это `false`.

Comment: Получается, когда я пишу ```int number = *(int*)b```, то обращаюсь к ячейке памяти, которая содержит в себе либо ```00000000``` или ```00000001```? И в зависимости от значения получаю 0 или 1 соответственно

Comment: @AlAvenger верно, но нет гарантии, что там нули слева, то есть там `xxxxxx01`. Я кстати дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Какое-то другое число получается, потому что **адрес** переменной приводится к инту. В 32-разрядной системе это будет выглядеть примерно как `0x124a53b0`

По внутреннему содержанию логические переменные есть 0 и 1, что вы и видите в первом случае

Comment: Что значит "по внутреннему"? В памяти?

Comment: Да. В памяти логическая переменная занимает байт со значением 0 или 1

Comment: А если быть точнее, то 0 или другое число, не обязательно 1.